# How to detect change in UISegmentedControl from a separate IBAction

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` button with three segments.
In `ViewController.m` this is working just fine -- pressing the buttons fires the correct methods.

I have another separate `UIButton` that when it is pressed it needs to first CHECK the state of the `UISegmentedControl` (to see which button is currently pressed) and then fire a method according to that segment value.

Here is my code for that separate `UIButton`. The button itself is working, but I cannot seem to figure out how to GET the current value of the segment of the `UISegmentedControl`.

Many thanks for any assistance here.
I am new to `OBJ-C`. I know how to do this in `VisualBasic`, so answers that are on the more verbose side would be most appreciated as I need to know the 'why'. Thank you.

```
- (IBAction)decodeButton:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *segment = [UISegmentedControl alloc];  // THIS DOES NOT WORK.

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
                decode(textToDecode);
    } else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
                decode1(textToDecode);
    } else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
                decode2(textToDecode); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/) is a Tutorial [using UISegmentedControl in iOS.](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/)

Just Create a Reference object and wire it properly to File Owner.

```
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
```

Then set property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * segmentedControl;
```

Synthesize in .m file

```
@synthesize segmentedControl;
```

Now You can Access the selected index at any time.

```
- (IBAction)decodeButton:(id)sender {

    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
                decode(textToDecode);
    } else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
                decode1(textToDecode);
    } else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
                decode2(textToDecode); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Siba. The Tutorial was exactly what I needed to see.
This code worked perfectly and the tutorial gave me a label to show -- which was my next task. 2013 is already starting out very well. I thank all of you who responded.

Answer (score 6):

Your code `alloc` every time `UISegmentedControl` in the button press action. So use the following code for `sUISegmentedControl` creation and its action .

```
 SegmentChangeView=[[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Segment1",@"Segment2",@"Segment3",nil]];
    SegmentChangeView.frame=CGRectMake(5, 44, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, 33);
    SegmentChangeView.selectedSegmentIndex=0;
    SegmentChangeView.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    SegmentChangeView.momentary = YES;
    [SegmentChangeView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    NSDictionary *attributes =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13],UITextAttributeFont,nil];
    [SegmentChangeView setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [SegmentChangeView addTarget:self action:@selector(SegmentChangeViewValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    SegmentChangeView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:SegmentChangeView];

-(IBAction)SegmentChangeViewValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)SControl
{
    if (SControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
          decode(textToDecode);
    }
    else if (SControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
    {
            decode1(textToDecode);
    }
else if (SControl.selectedSegmentIndex==2)
    {
            decode2(textToDecode);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `UISegmentedControl *segment = [UISegmentedControl alloc] ;` from your code, as it allocs anew instance of your UISegmentedControl every time, instead,

create an outlet for you `UISegmentController` like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * segment;
```

and then later at any point in your `viewcontroller.m` file, you can get the currently selected segment by using

```
segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

Hope this make sense,

Regards

Answer (score 2):

**Try like this**

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(id)sender
{
   UISegmentedControl *s = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

   if (s.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
   {
      //code
   }
   else
   {
      //code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code means you are creating a new Object on every click

```
 UISegmentedControl *segment = [UISegmentedControl alloc] ;
```

The thing you have to do take `IBOutlet` (Property) of your `segmentedControl` then I will work for you. dont create a new object in the button method. when you will make a IBOutlet it will be link with at `segmentControl` and your code will work that time . Thanks